# Degree of dissociation of strong electrolytes in concentrated solutions of ionic substances

Tags: acid-base, electrochemistry

Why is the dissociation of strong electrolytes complete in very dilute solutions of ionic substances but less likely to be so in more concentrated solutions?

Before seeing this, I thought a strong acid will always dissociate no matter the situation.

Comment: There is  a bigger possibility for ions to recombine in a more concentrated solution.